# Solidity: deploy contract, mint 50 nfts, and send nft to 50 hard coded addresses all in one step possible?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft

Is it possible and or advisable to, in one step, deploy a smart contract, have it mint 50 nfts and send those 50 nfts to 50 different addresses all in one transaction?

Or would it be better practice to split these 3 different actions into two different transactions?

Would love any references to existing smart contracts that do anything similar!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to run Solidity functions with long running for loops that may exhaust the available gas. Because you are minting 50 NFTs it is likely you cannot fit all the execution function to a single Ethereum transaction and you need to do minting in smaller batches.

Comment: The answer here[https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87616/47607] states that

```Also note, the original ERC-721 implementation already allows O(1) token creation, but only during contract deployment, as specified in ERC-721, and cited in ERC-2309: "Exception: during contract creation, any number of NFTs may be created and assigned without emitting Transfer."```

This contradicts your answer, does it not @Mikko?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: No it doesn't.  You cannot update Ethereum state for free. You are still going to pay the gas fee and if that's too high you need to split your transaction to several batches.